# I am getting transactionlargeexception error when sharing a photo with intent in android

Tags: android, kotlin, transactiontoolargeexception

This is my share code. I can share with StartActivity but the app crashes in the background.
The error is here and my app crashes.
Thank in advence.

```
val bitmapUri = Uri.parse(bitmapPath)
                val sendIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND)
                sendIntent.setType("image/*")
                sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, bitmapUri)
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, "share"))
```

---

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: android.os.TransactionTooLargeException: data parcel size 2706652 bytes
        at android.app.servertransaction.PendingTransactionActions$StopInfo.run(PendingTransactionActions.java:161)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:236)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7861)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:600)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:967)
     Caused by: android.os.TransactionTooLargeException: data parcel size 2706652 bytes
        at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)
        at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(BinderProxy.java:540)
        at android.app.IActivityTaskManager$Stub$Proxy.activityStopped(IActivityTaskManager.java:4627)
        at android.app.servertransaction.PendingTransactionActions$StopInfo.run(PendingTransactionActions.java:145)
```

Comment: That exception cannot be thrown from the code you posted.

Comment: what does it mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. Actually, the error was not from the code above. The problem was that I was sending a large data with bundle. **Remember, the reason for this error is that if you are using bundle, you have loaded big data on it.**